# Find longest repeat sub-sequence

Tags: python-re

I have a random string like:

```
a = "aabcaaabbccccdabbbbbc"
```

I want to find out the longest repeat substring and it's length. In this case the answer should be "bbbbb" and 5. 
What is the regular expression way?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = "aabcaaabbccccdabbbbbc"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w)(\1)+')
max_pattern_len, max_pattern = 0, ''
for match in pattern.finditer(a):
    m = match.group()
    if len(m) > max_pattern_len:
        max_pattern_len = len(m)
        max_pattern = m

print(max_pattern_len, max_pattern)
```

Output:

```
(5, 'bbbbb')
```